# Continue out of exception clause?

Tags: python

My research says no but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to handle the following scenario:

```
try:
    some_function()
except Exception:
    # process some data to determine how to handle the error
    if not some_statement:
        # do some_function() in a different way
        #### Here I want to continue to the remaining code after the exception
    # a bunch of code if some_statement==True
# remaining code
```

The obvious solution is to just put everything after the if statement into else but I'm already indented more than I'd like.

Is there some built-in I'm missing? It seems like it would fit with syntax to be able to continue or break out of an exception but it seems those are only for loops.

Comment: Can you put the relevant code in a function and use `return`?

Comment: What you want would require a `goto` statement, but Python doesn't have that.

Comment: "a bunch of code if some_statement == True" - we don't see any definition or assignment to "some_statement" in your code so its unclear why you have that where you do.

Comment: What do you want to do if the second "try" of some_function() fails?

Comment: I don't understand what code you mean with "the remaining code after the exception".

Answer (score 1):

User @Barmar confirmed my suspicion.

For some applications it certainly makes sense to split off into functions, but in my situation, some_function() is a smaller part of a script that only applies to a very specific use case. Doing so would make my main function more concise, but the functions would serve no other purpose and in my opinion, would only make the script less readable.

So I will live with the extra indentation knowing there's no better way.

Thank you all!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to be clear as much as possible. Write in the comment if you want something else please.

```
try:
    some_function()
except Exception as e:
    if not some_statement:
        # do some_function() in a different way
        some_alternative_function()
        # 2. way is, you can pass a parameter to the function
        # some_function(blabla=True)
        # 3. way is, you can wrap the whole try-except clause with a function and make a recursive call here
    else:
        # a bunch of code if some_statement==True
        handle_error_some_statement_true(e)
else:
    # code to execute if some_function() did not raise an exception
    post_some_function_success()
```

Comment: I think this solves 2/3 of your problem even if you don't accept the `if not some_statement` if-clause.